# How do I deploy a dart web app to execute a system shell script?

Tags: android, dart

I want to make web apps that run system shell scripts on my phone.

Of course when I `import dart:io;`,  in the dart editor, I get;

> Failed to load a file dart:io ...

I understand that dart:io is prohibited in client code. Is there a solution to execute such local system scripts from a web app or some alternative gui control on android?

**Why?**

Because these would be interesting for my daily use, simple to have up an running and can help me to learn about dart. Or is this a totally misguided (and prohibited) use of dart?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the short answer to your question is "no".  It would be a significant breach of security if a web app could run shell scripts on a phone.  Specifically, Dart code compiled to Javascript to run in the Android browser should certainly not be able to execute files.  That would be a hole so big in security that you could drive a bus through it.  You can't even execute shell scripts from Javascript in a browser on your desktop... why should it be any different on Android.